# Android Studio 3.4 Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-multidex

I am using two different libraries, but they both have same base(webrtc). Because of which there is a duplicity in many classes. Therefore, android studio is not letting me create an apk.

I tried below solution which isn't working.

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Also, I have **multiDexEnabled true** in build.gradle file.

Can anyone please provide a solution to the issue?

**EDIT:**
Here is the error that I am getting.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForBonumHealthDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForBonumHealthDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/webrtc/NetworkMonitor;
```

Comment: Refer this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309249/getting-multidex-error-even-after-setting-min-sdk-21

Comment: @Kabir Tired. not working.

Comment: It's a dependency issue. Please update the version of each dependency with auto-suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try the solution provided in the link below

https://medium.com/@nhancv/android-deal-with-multidex-fix-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-8daf4d2135af

Answer (score 0):

It's **not a multi dex issue** (although it says multiple dex files define X).

It's because **you have duplication in your dependencies.**
According to error, there's a class `org.webrtc.NetworkMonitor` that exists in more than one place.

Checkout your code and see why it's been defined again. Any libraries causing this?

You can search around all the libraries you have added for this class to find the source of the problem.

One case that might cause duplication is that both libraries include one or more libraries that have the same classes which dex maker can not decide which one to use. In this situation, you can use **excluding** the dependency of one library.

Assume I have made a custom RxJava library, and also have a library that uses RxJava.
When syncing Gradle, this will cause duplication. To resolve this I can exclude the RxJava used by that library, so it will not be included to classPath and I can use mine with no duplication issue.

```
implementation("android.arch.work:work-rxjava2:${versions.workManager}")
  { 
     exclude group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', module: 'rxjava'
  }
```

These means don't include `io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava` from work manager library, in the dependency tree (So you will add one yourself)

So **you can exclude that library from one of those libraries**, so the other one will add it, or **you can exclude from both of them and add that library yourself.**

Comment: Yes. I am using 2 different libraries. Both pointing to same class. I cannot edit those libraries.

Comment: I have not tested this: but see if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38886815/6678991

Comment: Can't you use another library to resolve duplication? And one more question: Are these classes bundled to libraries? Or they use them as libraries? I mean are they using other libraries that cause duplication?

Comment: 1: I can't use other library. 2: Yes. Both libraries are using one same library, that is why there is duplication of classes.

Comment: Well, sorry. I can't help you with your issue.